# Coefficient sign flips changing from OLS to Random Effects model

Tags: regression, panel-data, stata, random-effects-model

Though many posts discussed about possible reasons for signs flipping, I haven't seen anyone the same as mine. I have two dummy variables named A & B. In an OLS regression, A is positive and B is negative. However, when I use xtreg,re in Stata referring to a random effects model, it becomes that A is negative and B is positive. I was taught that the interpretation for dummies is no change in RE models, so I think I still shall understand A as "compared to, for example, only eating meat (equals 0), eating both meats and vegetables (equals 1) is healthier (assume our DV is a variable representing the larger the healthier)". Then, what RE model estimates here is wrong. What are the implications behind this difference? I couldn't figure out.

BTW: I have an unbalanced panel.

Comment: Do you have unit-level dummies in the OLS?

Comment: @dimitriy No, I found when I added individual fixed effects, the signs became the same as in FE or RE model.

Comment: @FinelyHuaxin Does that clear things up?